# "require_channel: https" causes Error 310, Too Many Redirects

Tags: symfony

If I try and force certain areas of my site to use https I get

`Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`

If I just use https:// myself the page renders fine, it's only when I force it to use https.

This is my security.yml, but I get the same error if I use annotations too.

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_MERCHANT:    ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_MERCHANT]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /dashboard
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, role: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https}
        - { path: ^/invoice/new, role: ROLE_MERCHANT, requires_channel: https}
        - { path: ^/invoice, role: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https}
```

I'm running on nginx rather than Apache too.

Comment: Doing what action do you get the error?

Comment: /dashboard, /invoice & /invoice/new

Comment: try to cover `/login` with https. Also very heplful if you write urls where you redirected. Try to trace it with http sniffers(dont know browsers can show it or not with redirect loop)

Comment: Use chrome developer toolbar -> network tab and activate 'Preserve log upon navigation' - that show pages that prosecution in redirects

Comment: Even on /login I get the same problem, looking at it in Chrom's dev toolbar it is not redirecting to any intermediate page, just itself each time.

Comment: Have you [set up scheme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html) in your `routing.yml`?

Comment: are you running apache as reverse proxy with nginx?

Comment: @jkucharovic, Yes, I have set up the scheme in routing. I've tried it with & without that in the config.

Comment: @Roberto: No, I am not running Apache at all on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

To your nginx vhost, that will help Symfony recognize that the request is a SSL request, symfony is checking against the HTTPS global variable to check if the request is SSL or not and redirect acordingly, if that variable is not set inside by the webserver on a SSL request symfony will try to redirect causing the loop :)

More info over here.. http://blog.servergrove.com/2011/04/04/symfony2-quick-tip-generateurl-with-https-on-nginx/