# Have absolute url generated using https but not requiring https

Tags: php, forms, symfony, https, load-balancing

I have a web app that is on a load balancer.  The connections to the load balancer are secure using https, and my load balancer communicates to my web server using http.  This is secure enough for my use case since the web server can only accept traffic from the load balancer that is already authenticated.

My problem is that I have several forms using FOSMessageBundle that create routes using the current scheme.  The web server thinks incoming connections are using http so routes are generated with http.  This now becomes a security risk and I cannot submit the form on most browsers due to the inconsistent schemes.

Here is the line form the twig file that I need to override and correct:

```
 {% set formAction %}{{ url('fos_message_thread_undelete', {'threadId': thread.id}) }}{% endset %}
```

If I require https ([using the method form the symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html)) for the fos route above, the route generated is correct, but a redirect loop occurs on submission because the web server cannot accept https and my load balancer is automatically setting and redirecting any http to https.

I used a quick and dirty solution to manually enter https in my route and use the path function to create the rest of the url, but this is not proper coding.  I tested it and the form is submitted with https to the load balancer which then sends it to the web server with http.

Is there a way to generate a url in symfony that is always generated with https but does not require https?

I was looking through the docs and found [Schema-relative URLs](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-new-url-generation-options) which seems to be the right direction, but the documentation implies its for accessing external files, not for form routes.  Does anyone know if its appropriate to use this in my situation:

```
{{ url('fos_message_thread_undelete', {'threadId': thread.id}, true) }}
```

Here are some other questions that are somewhat similar but none had an answer for what I am trying to accomplish:

[“require_channel: https” causes Error 310, Too Many Redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250438/require-channel-https-causes-error-310-too-many-redirects/17983835#17983835)

[Forcing HTTPS with Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521392/forcing-https-with-symfony)

I am using apache 2.4 and Symfony 2.6.

Comment: Have you read through this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html

Comment: Yes, i setup my trusted proxies and security groups.  I was not sure if I can include that in my controler/twig file.  I was not having success using getScheme() but will test that more.

Comment: Is your load balancer actually sending an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to my question for creating https in twig, but not requiring https for the form submission is to use Schema-relative URLs:

```
{{schema_parameter}}{{ url('fos_message_thread_undelete', {'threadId': thread.id}, true) }}
```